# Symfony DQL syntax error while selecting last and next record

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to get next and previous record in my database, this is my first time using DQL and I don't really understand why it doesn't work.

Here's how my custom query look like:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery(
        'SELECT id 
        FROM SITEArticlesBundle:Article
        WHERE
            id = (SELECT id
            FROM SITEArticlesBundle:Article
            WHERE ? > 2 LIMIT 1)
        OR
            id = (SELECT id 
            FROM SITEArticlesBundle:Article
            WHERE ? < 2 LIMIT 1)', $rsm);
    $query->setParameter(1, $id);
    $query->setParameter(2, $id);
    $nextAndPrevNews = $query->execute();
```

I want to get array of 2 id, like that:

```
[
    ['id' => 1]
    ['id' => 3]
]
```

But I get a SQL syntax error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':Article
>   WHERE
>   id = (SELECT id
>   FROM ' at line 2

I would be really grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is the colon character in the table name. That character isn't allowed, unless the table name is escaped.

I suspect that `SITEArticlesBundle:Article` isn't the actual identifier for the MySQL table. In a native query, you need to specify the actual name of the MySQL table.

If that is your tablename, then you can enclose it in backtick characters:

```
 FROM `SITEArticlesBundle:Article`
```

I'm not sure why you'd be comparing the value of $id with a literal 2, and not comparing that to the value of the `id` column in the table. I don't get it.

Unless you are trying to pass in the column name as a bind parameter, which won't work. You can only pass in *values* to a prepared SQL statement, you can't pass identifiers or keywords or other SQL constructs in as bind parameters.

Personally, I'd avoid the OR condition and the subqueries, and just use a UNION ALL operation.

```
 SELECT MAX(p.id) AS id
   FROM `SITEArticlesBundle:Article` p
  WHERE p.id < ?
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT MIN(n.id) AS id
   FROM `SITEArticlesBundle:Article` n
  WHERE n.id > ?
```